# How Do I Manually Wire A Spring Boot Integration Test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Normally, I would test the web layer in a Spring project like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SpringBootDemoApplicationTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @LocalServerPort
    int randomServerPort;
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
```

However, I currently have a difficult back end that requires a specific `@TestConfiguration` class to manually instantiate the test dependencies using beans.

This ultimately means that I can't use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation as it will try to create conflicting beans and fail to instantiate others.

If I am not using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, I can manually create the `TestRestTemplate` instead of autowiring it, but what do I need to do to start the embedded local server on a random port?

Answer (score 0):

I would still continue using `@SpringBootTest`, and combine that with using `@Profile` on your configuration classes.

That way you could have a configuration which is only used during tests, by using `@ActiveProfiles` on your `@SpringBootTest` classes. In the same way you can turn other config classes on or off depending on whether you want them to load or not.

For example on your test would have the following

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("unittest")
public class SpringBootDemoApplicationTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    ...
}
```

Then create a configuration class which will instantiate your components the way you want them in test

```
@Profile("unittest")
@Configuration
public void TestConfiguration {
   ...
}
```

And you can use profiles to stop your other configuration class from loading during tests.

```
@Profile("!unittest")
@Configuration
public void ProdConfiguration {
   ...
}
```

Comment: So do I add the `@Profile("!unittest")` to the production classes?

Comment: Yes you can do that. The other way is to add something like  `@Profile("production")` to your production config. And then ensure that your active profiles has 'production' when actually running the application. But during tests your active profiles does not include 'production' meaning all classes annotated with `Profile("production")` will not be loaded